# Update table but by first match and then by second

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a historic table from where I need to update my current table but by order based on a column

First look at that last date on historic table and update and only if no matches update from the next last date and so on.

My idea is put a loop by getting the max date and then join recursively till the min date in historic table.

Any inputs would be highly appreciated.

Historic table below. Now consider am updating my table and it has S_Numb as 18992 so no match but if its 1891 it should update ABC1. There is no date field in the table to be updated.

```
S_Numb  S_Name  S_date
19891   ABC1    2017-01-13
19891   ABC2    2017-01-06
19891   ABC3    2016-12-30
11631   ABC2    2016-12-16
11631   ABC3    2016-12-09
11631   ABC4    2016-12-02
11631   ABC5    2016-11-25
11631   ABC6    2016-11-18
11631   ABC7    2016-11-11
13213   ABC1    2016-11-04
13213   ABC2    2016-10-28
13213   ABC3    2016-10-21
13213   ABC4    2016-10-14
13213   ABC5    2016-10-07
13213   ABC6    2016-09-30
13213   ABC7    2016-09-16
```

Comment: What have you tried? Show your table structure as well with some sample data.

Comment: I have added a table now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `cross apply` to get the most recent value like this:

**cross [apply](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx)**:

```
--update c set c.ColumnToUpdate = x.ColumnToUpdate
select x.ColumnToUpdate, c.*
  from Current as c
    cross apply (
      select top 1
          h.ColumnToUpdate
        from History 
        where h.Id = c.Id
        order by h.Date desc
           ) as x
  where c.ColumnToUpdate != x.ColumnToUpdate;
```

Updated with some code comments from question update:

```
update c set c.S_Name = x.S_Name
--select x.S_Name, c.*
  from Current as c
    cross apply (  /* only returns rows where there is a result */
      select top 1 -- only first result
          h.S_Name -- column to update
        from History 
        where h.S_Numb = c.S_Numb -- column to match on
        order by h.Date desc  -- most recent date first
           ) as x
  where c.S_Name != x.S_Name;
```

Comment: Awesome, this worked. It took time to understand the logic.

Answer (score 0):

We could use some sample data, but assuming each row in both tables has an ID called SomeID, and that the historic table has a time stamp called YourCreatedTimeStamp, and the value you'd like updated in a field called SomeField...

```
update CurrentTable 
    set SomeField = 
       (
         select SomeField
         from HistoricTable 
             inner join 
                 (
                 select 
                      SomeId
                     ,max(YourCreatedTimeStamp) as LastCreatedTS
                 from HistoricTable
                 group by SomeId
                 ) LastEntryForEachId
             on HistoricTable.SomeId = LastEntryForEachId.SomeId
                 and HistoricTable.YourCreatedTs = LastEntryForEachId.LastCreatedTs)
where SomeId = [The Id You Are Interested in Updating)
```

Comment: I have updated a sample table. The current table doesn't have time stamp

Comment: The created time stamp is only necessary in the historic table.

Comment: Yes its like historic records based on that I need to do the matching, but I want to pull the latest one. Solution provided by @SqlZim worked for me.